# Add UIViews as subviews to UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I created 2 UIViews with a Xib file. How do I need to add them to a `UIViewController`?

Comment: What have you done so far to try to add the subviews?

Comment: you need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the firstView in the View Controller and do something like this:

```
firstView *firstView = [[firstView alloc] init];
```

or this:

```
UIView *firstView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"firstView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

and then, this:

```
[self.view addSubview:firstView];
```

If you need to access a subview of firstView, you gotta set a tag in the firstView class to the subview you want to access:

```
[subview setTag:100];
```

and then you retrieve that view in the View Controller like this:

```
UIView *subView = [firstView viewWithTag:100];
```